# python rock paper scissors beginner

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a basic game without functions but I have some bug and don't know what the problem is. My software or my code. I understand concepts(so decided not to write full code for the game). Please, tell me how to fix it. [That's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JpLD.png)

Comment: Your program is only 5 lines long, and the error message is only 10 _words_.  You can copy & paste them both here far more easily than we can all download and squint at an image.

Answer (score 1):

you need to indent that last line (follows the : of the if statement)

```
if player1 == 'rock' and\
player2 == 'scissors':
    print 'Player 1 wins.'
```

Also, welcome to SO, and please post code in your question. It's easier for us to work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped. I programmed in c++ a little before but I have never had indentation problems there.

Comment: @TimSp that's because python uses indentation instead of bracketing for block scopes. Love it, or hate it; it's the way it is ;)